# Не могу разобраться с итерацией

Tags: python, python-3.x

Не получается разобраться с итерациями.  Отрабатывает 2 раза, как и должно, но возвращает весь список. По документации я так понимаю оно должно обработать каждый элемент списка. Я уже пробовал внутри `__next__` создать еще цикл, в общем не получается. Нужно, что бы обрабатывало элементы списка, где я допустил ошибку?

```
class Valuefilter(object):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        self.list_data = args
        self.num = 0

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        if self.num != 2:
            self.num += 1
            for x in self.list_data:
                return x
        else:
            raise StopIteration


args = [33, 12, 17, 88, 4]
iter = Valuefilter(*args)
for i in iter:
    print(i)
```

Comment: В вашем `__next__` прописано вернуть первый элемент списка ровно два раза — это у меня и происходит и печатается 33 два раза. Что вы хотели реализовать этим кодом на самом деле, я понять не смог

Comment: словами опишите, что код должен делать, приведите явный пример желаемого ввода/вывода. Явно опишите чем фактический вывод из вашего отличается

Comment: Я хотел, что бы отображалась так: 33, 12, 17, 88, 4. Элемент находятся внутри списка и каждый из них имеет свой итератор, если я все правильно понял

Comment: @S.Dior вы хотите `print(*args, sep=', ')` написать? Чем результат вызова print отличается от желаемого¶ Не помещайте информацию необходимую для ответа в комментарии, обновите ваш вопрос вместо этого. Нажмите [edit]

Answer (score 0):

На сколько я вас понял, вам нужно сделать примерно так:

```
def __iter__(self):
    for _ in range(2):
        yield from self.list_data
```

Comment: код в вопросе заменить на: `print(*itertools.repeat(args, 2))`, в вашем коде хотя бы `yield from self.list_data` можно использовать¶ Есть тонкое отличие: `iter(it) is it` нарушается (разница между iterator в частности и iterable вообще).